# What is wrong with this code? Copying Cells From Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, copy, copy-paste

I keep getting an error message when running this code.   I am trying to copy a range of cells from one workbook to another.   Can anybody tell me what is wrong? Thank you.

```
Sub Appointments()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

''''''''Declare Variables
Dim Appts As Workbook
Dim Source As Workbook
Dim EOD As String

'''''''''Set Variable Values
Set Appts = ActiveWorkbook

'''''''''Open Report
MsgBox "Please Open The End Of Day File"

EOD = Application.GetOpenFilename
If EOD = "False" Then Exit Sub

Workbooks.Open EOD
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook

Appts.Cells(3 & "E", 43 & "E").Value = Source.Cells(3 & "D", 43 & "D").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `Cells`, the two arguments are Row Index and Column Index.  It is looking for two numbers to indicate one specific cell.  If you're trying to copy the range from E3 to E43, use `Range("E3:E43")`.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221403%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for more info on how to use Cells.

Comment: Actually when I switched it from Set Source=ActiveWorkbook to Set Source=ThisWorkbook, it corrected the issue.  I'm not really sure what the difference between these to commands are, but if it works it works.  I did however take your advice and use Range("E3:E43") because it is a lot cleaner.  I appreciate the help.  Now, it's time to get to the real hard stuff.  I can't believe I wasted a couple hours with something I've done dozens of times in the past, and I still don't know why it didn't work.  But oh well, now its time to create the array to import a couple thousand EOD reports. Wahoo!

Answer (score 0):

Error might occurs at `Appts.Cells(3 & "E", 43 & "E").Value = Source.Cells(3 & "D", 43 & "D").Value`.

Already thunderblaster explain why `cells` wont accept strings.

May be u could need to below code.

```
Appts.activesheet.range("E3:E43").Value = Source.activesheet.range("E3:E43").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Set Appts = ActiveWorkbook
```

to this:

```
Set Appts = Thisworkbook 'Just to be safe
```

And this line:

```
Appts.Cells(3 & "E", 43 & "E").Value = Source.Cells(3 & "D", 43 & "D").Value
```

To this line:

```
Appts.Range(Cells(3, "E"),Cells(43,"E")).Value = _
Source.Range(Cells(3, "D"), Cells(43, "D")).Value
```

Remember that `Cells` syntax is `Cells(RowIndexnum,ColIndexNum)` which accepts numeric values.
Your code is trying to pass a `String` argument like this `Cells(3 & "E", 43 & "E")` which
results to this: `Cells(3E,43E)` and thus creates `Runtime Error: 5`.

Also if you are reffering to a range of cell for example `E3:E43`, you cannot use cell alone.
Instead, use `Range` with this syntax `Range(CellAddress,Cell2Address)`.

Example:

```
Range("E3:E43")
```

is equal to this:

```
Range("E3", "E43")
```

And is equal to this using `Cells`.

```
Range(Cells(3,"E"),Cells(43,"E"))
```

Hope this helps.